# How can i open a DST file in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, dst, dst-embroidery

In my iphone application, i want to open a .dst file.
DST file is an embroidary file which can be open as an image file.
Is there any sdk or code to view this file in an ios application?
Or can it be convertable to other format?
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can any one please guide me, if i get the following details, how can i draw it on screen. The details as: ST:  10889
CO: 19
+X:  880
-X:  354
+Y: 1151
-Y:  371
AX:+   62
AY:+   87
MX:+    0
MY:+    0

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can read DST files as NSData, but then you have to parse the data and create stitches on your own. Take this info as a starting point: http://www.achatina.de/sewing/main/DST.HTM, AFAIK there's no library / framework available to the public.

If you're looking for an existing app to view / edit / convert DSTs as well as other embroidery file formats, just search for "StitchBuddy"...

BTDT, Mattes